# Thread.Sleep() in C#: Does it sleep the thread the object was instantiated in, or the thread i am calling the method from?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a program in C# that has a main thread where I create a bunch of instances of the class Skill. Examples: _fire, _ice, _thunderbolt. As you might have guessed, these are various magical skills.

From the main thread I spawn a second thread and use it to do a lot of background work. Among other things I want to have that thread call a method in the class Skill, called useSkill().

**The Question:** If I place a Thread.Sleep(1000) in that useSkill() method, will it sleep the main thread, where the object was instantiated, or will it sleep the background thread, where the method was called from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Typing `Class.Method` into google almost always will return an MSDN link as one of the first results. Here's [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx). MSDN is the documentation for (among other things) the .NET framework.

Comment: Having your cursor on the method and pressing F1 almost always will open the MSDN page in your default browser as long as you use Visual Studio and your pointer is on a standard .net method.

Comment: Thanks George, Zenuka, et al. I did find the MSDN article on it, but was not able to draw the correct conclusion from that article. Accepting Zenuka's answer when timer allows. Thanks again!

Comment: "current thread" in the  documentation seems fairly clear.

Comment: Peter, even though something is clear to you does not mean it is clear to all others. That at least, is fairly clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(..)` blocks/sleeps the current thread: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

So if you would instantiate the object in the main thread but call the `UseSkill()` method which contains the `Thread.Sleep(..)` from thread A then thread A would be blocked or sleeping. If you however call the `UseSkill()` method from the constructor and you instantiate the object in the main thread, the main thread will be blocked/sleeped.

Also, you could use the Threads window to debug and see in which thread the blocking would occur (go to Debug -> Windows -> Threads **while debugging**).

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP - this means it will sleep the thread which called `Thread.Sleep`